# Is it possible to pass conditionals through a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an iterative way to run through a bunch of different statements that are variable and will assign a value to a series based on the boolean result (`np.where` was my function of choice). I am trying to make it not look like a complete mess, so I had the thought of passing dictionary values through a loop.

The below code doesn't work, but looking to do something similar to this approach. Is it even possible to pass conditionals through a dictionary like this? Also open to alternative ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'test': None})


d = {'a' : {
        'arg'     : df['A'] == 2,
        't_value' : 'Value Found',
        'f_value' : df['test']
        },
     'b' : {
        'arg'     : df['A'] > 3,
        't_value' : 'Value Found',
        'f_value' : df['test']
        }
     }

for item in d:
    df['test'] = np.where([d[item]['arg']], [d[item]['t_value']], [d[item]['f_value']])
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary `list` brackets and they work just fine: `np.where(d[item]['arg'], d[item]['t_value'], d[item]['f_value'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do any of the following -

**pd.where with multiple conditions**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'test': None})

#conditions
a = df['A']==2 
b = df['A']>3


df['test'] = df['test'].where(~(a|b), 'Value Found')

print(df)
```

```
   A         test
0  1         None
1  2  Value Found
2  3         None
3  4  Value Found
4  5  Value Found
```

**List comprehension**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'test': None})

df['test'] = ['Value Found' if i==2 or i>3 else None for i in df['A']]

print(df)
```

```
   A         test
0  1         None
1  2  Value Found
2  3         None
3  4  Value Found
4  5  Value Found
```

However, if you do want to define a dict of dicts and use `np.where` with each condition mentioned, as @Chris mentioned, please remove the `[ ]` from each of the paramaters to the `np.where`

```
df['test'] = np.where(d[item]['arg'], d[item]['t_value'], d[item]['f_value'])
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't catch that the brackets were the problem....thank you.